# Prove that a function whose derivative is bounded is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose that $f$ is a real-valued function on $\Bbb R$ whose derivative exists at each point and is bounded. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Could you provide any work you've done on this problem already?

Comment: This is a trivial consequence of the mean value theorem. It is more interesting to note that $f$ can be uniformly continuous, even if its derivative is unbounded. You'll see [examples here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118665/why-if-f-is-unbounded-then-f-isnt-uniformly-continuous). One of them is easy to extend to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since $f'$ is bounded then there's $M>0$ s.t.
$$|f'(x)|\leq M\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$
hence by mean value theorem we find
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|\quad \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$
so $f$ is a lipschitzian function on $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore it's s uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 11):

Hint: $f(a)-f(b)=f'(\xi)(a-b)$.