# Which of the following is not uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

Which of the following is not uniformly continuous?

1.$f_1(x)=|x|$

2.$f_2(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

3.$f_3(x)=\sin x^2$

4.$f_4(x)=\ln(1+x^2)$

5.$f_5(x)=e^{-x}$

My solution:$f_1(x)=|x|$ is lipschitz so uniformly continuous.

$\lim_{ x\to\pm \infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}=0$.Also $f_2(x)$ is continuous,so it is uniformly continuous

$f_3(x),f_4(x),f_5(x)$ are not uniformly continuous.Am i right?

Comment: What is your argument for$ f_3,f_4 $and $f_5?$

Comment: @AlexR is $sin(1/x)$ continuous?

Comment: @AlexR My argument is "a continuous function on an unbounded interval is uniformly continuous if either it is lipschitz or limits at infinity exists".You can check this result from some analysis book.

Comment: @AlexR Yes you also need limit at 0

Comment: So my argument is correct.

Comment: @Math So the correct statement is "a continuous function on an unbounded interval is uniformly continuous if either it is lipschitz or limits at the interval bounds exist". Yes, your application is correct; I will delete all prior comments. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Mesih for $f_3$ consider $x_n=\sqrt{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and $y_n=\sqrt{n\pi}$ then you can see $|x_n-y_n|\to 0$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\to1\neq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function with bounded derivative is uniformly continuous (see for instance [Prove that a function whose derivative is bounded is uniformly continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377531)).  Hence 4) is uniformly continuous.

Comment: ok yes you are right,and what are your thoughts about 5th?

Comment: I agree with you about 5 (not uniformly continuous) because of the rapid (unbounded) growth rate of $e^{-x}$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: In the case of $log(1+x^2)$, there is a rapid growth at $\infty$.

Comment: @paw88789 If a person uses this result before 'A function with bounded derivative is uniform convergence'. Why does this function show dual behaviour? Please explain.