# prove or disprove Lipchitz function

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Prove or disprove that $f(x)= -7x-3$ is Lipchitz on $\mathbb{R}$

My answer is:

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|-7x-3-(-7y-3)|$

$=|-7x+7y|=|-7(x-y)|=7|x-y|$

If the answer is equal not less than or equal can we say it is Lipchitz?
And also they asked if it is Lipchitz in $\mathbb{R}$ so is this an answer on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Isn't the inequality $1≤1$ holds true?

Comment: yes true so if my answer is = so true and same if my answer is <.

Comment: but in class they teach us lipchitz over close interval but here its is over R is it te same?;

Comment: You can continue with $\ldots =7|x-y| \leq 7|x-y|$ **OR** $\ldots =7|x-y| < 7.1|x-y|$ **OR** $\ldots =7|x-y| \leq 7.1|x-y|$ **OR** $\ldots =7|x-y| \leq 42|x-y|$ etc. This last one is because for something like, this [one likes to introduce the number 42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)!

Comment: I think there is a theorem that if $f$ differentiable and $f'$ is bounded then it is lipschitz. Here $f'=-7$ for all $x$. So it satisfies Lipschitz contion on $\mathbb R$. Please let me know if there are no such theorems.

Comment: *Please let me know if there are no such theorems.* --- If true, this would be VERY difficult to know (and even more difficult to show)! Fortunately, this is NOT true --- fortunately, because a "disproof that there are no such theorems" can be done [by giving a counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/377531/13130).

Comment: ok thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. For your query in comment:

The definition of Lipschitz function is:

If $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $f:A→\mathbb{R}$ is function. Then, $f$ is said to be Lipschitz on $A$ if there exists a constant $K>0$ such that,

$|f(x)-f(y)|≤K|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in A$

See that, in definition $A$ is subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So $A$ may be equals to $\mathbb{R}$ itself.