# Supremum for the derivative of differentiable functions on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Where does it follow from that the derivative of a differentiable function on a closed interval is bounded above/below? Specifically, let $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = cx^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$. By what property is $f'(x)$ bounded on $(a,b)$ so that is has a supremum?

Comment: You are lucky that $f'$ is continuous on this interval, so that $f'$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval, hence is bounded. But in general, $f'$ need not be bounded. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118665/why-if-f-is-unbounded-then-f-isnt-uniformly-continuous/118798) , for example.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I see. So we could just make the extrapolation from the interval of $(a, b)$ to $[a, b]$, since $f$ is continuous on the latter, and state that as a continuous on a closed and bounded interval, $f'$ attains both its maximum and minimum value?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant