Motivating continuity vs. uniform continuity on $\mathbb{R}$
I have been teaching real analysis for a while now, but I still feel as though I am not able to explain why we should care about uniform continuity.
At first, I simply passed it off as an upgrade of "normal" continuity.  Basically, a "nice" continuity.  This isn't untrue, but it isn't particularly interesting.
I've also explained it from the "uniform" perspective.  Students can see the "delta which works for all epsilon" point that I make, but again, not especially motivating.
I assign as homework to prove that "uniformly continuous image of a Cauchy sequence is Cauchy", but again, it's tough for the weaker students to recognize why we care about this.
Later, I added a note to my lessons about two behaviors of continuous functions which indicate an ABSENCE of uniformly continuity:

Being unbounded on a bounded domain, like $1/x$ on $(0,1]$.
Having an unbounded slope as $x\to\pm\infty$.

This helped some, but it more illustrated what uniform continuity is NOT, rather than what it is.
Finally, I found this wonderful post which (among other things) helped me to recognize the importance of the theorem "$f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous if an only if it can be continuously extended to the closure of $D$."
While this last point is a useful fact and provides a quick visual check for uniform continuity as well (which I love), I still don't have a good idea how to motivate uniform continuity on $\mathbb{R}$.
For example, I can prove that $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ are uniformly continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$, and that $f(x)=x^2$ is not.  I can also relate that back to the idea that "Having unbounded slope as $x\to\pm\infty$" prevents a function from being uniformly continuous.  Is there any way to revisit the "extends continuously" idea here? (I'm assuming no, since the closure of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, of course.)  Can I do more to intuitively understand the difference between these two functions that doesn't rely on the "uniform delta" idea?

Allow me to point out that having unbounded slope as $x \to \pm \infty$ does not prevent a function from being uniformly continuous.

@Adayah Can you give me a counterexample of this?  I was under the impression that part (b) of this question was true: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118665/why-if-f-is-unbounded-then-f-isnt-uniformly-continuous

Part (b) is correct, but unbounded slope is more like (c), which is incorrect. Anyway, consider the function $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is equal to $n$ on the interval $\left[n, n+\frac{1}{n^2}\right]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t) , \text{d} t$ has unbounded slope, but is uniformly continuous. Also a modification of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ would work, but it's a bit cumbersome to describe.

You could initially introduce uniform continuity not as a standalone idea, but by proving the property holds for continuous functions on a compact interval, or by showing it is necessary and sufficient for being able to continuously extend a function on a bounded set to its closure. Then name that property 'uniform continuity', and give the general definition, and note that it can apply to functions on an unbounded domain as well.
